# Transformation syntax with shortcuts to a more explicit syntax for an equation

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to write the following code line without the signs @#%^&*?!

```
Sequence @@ (XMLNote[#1, m] &) /@ attributes
```

I have made this code but it seems that it should be a slight difference since I no longer the good result in my program

```
Apply[Sequence, Map[(XMLNote[#1, m]) &, attributes]]
```

In fact, I started to use Mathematica not a long time ago and for the moment, I prefer to use a more explicit syntax in my code.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: If you detest the nonalphanumerics, you can certainly go further: `Apply[Sequence, Map[Function[z, XMLNote[z, m]], attributes]]`

Comment: perfect, thank you.
And what was the mistake in my translation?
Otherwise, I don't detest the nonalphanumerics but when I have nested functions, I'm a bit lost when I have too much nonalphanumerics

Comment: Before that: could you clarify the " I no longer the good result in my program"? Why did you say that it didn't work anymore after making things all explicit?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The two codes were equivalent. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bichoy Thank you for your answer. Very interesting and useful for me.

Comment: If you think his answer was helpful, you can click the check mark in his answer to show your gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

How about getting Mathematica to do the work for us?

```
FullForm[Sequence @@ (XMLNote[#1, m] &) /@ attributes ] // HoldForm
```

Which yields:

```
Apply[Sequence,Map[Function[XMLNote[Slot[1],m]],attributes]]
```

These two expressions are formally equivalent in every single way (they are a different syntax for the same thing). If they yield different results, there must be a bug in some other place in the code, or in how each of them is actually used.